# Hijacking, redirecting, display output with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, winapi

I am a new programmer with little experience but I am in the process of learning Python 2.7. I use Python(x,y) or Spydar as the programs are called on Windows 7.

The main packages I'm using are `numpy`, `pil` and potentially `win32gui`.

I am currently trying to write a program to mine information from a 3rd-party software. This is against their wishes and they have made it difficult. I'm using `ImageGrab` and then `numpy` to get some results. This however, or so i belive, forces me to keep the window I want to read in focus, which is not optimal.

I'm wondering if there is any way to hijack the whole window and redirect the output directly into a "virtual" copy, just so I can have it running in the background?

When looking at the demos for `win32api`, there is a script called `desktopmanager`. I never got it to work, probably since I'm running Windows 7, that's supposed to create new desktops. I don't really know how multiple desktops work but if they run in parallel, there may be a way to create a new desktop around a current window. I don't know how, it's just a thought so far.

The reason it's not working for me is not that it's not creating a new desktop, it's that once it's been created, I can't return from it. The taskbar icon nor the taskbar itself ever appears.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that might work would be to do something like so:

- get the window handle (FindWindow() or something similar, there are a few ways to do this)
- get the window dimensions (GetClientRect() or GetWindowRect())
- get the device context for the window (GetWindowDC())
- get the image data from the window (BitBlt() or similar)

It is possible that you will need elevated privelages to access another processes window dc, if so you may need to inject code/dll into the target process space to do this.

HTH.

Comment: yeah that takes me about halfway there, thou it seems that i always have to display the data i retrive. Since the end goal is to get it into numpy it would be better if i could transfer it into a matrix directly rather than an other picture. Still, this is great, thanks.